# Tupla de valores usando o mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho um formulário onde tem dois campos, um serviço e outro valor, para cada serviço o usuário tem que colocar um valor, depois que o usuário escolher, consulto no banco quantas linhas vão me retorna com esse filtro. Para o procedimento eu passo dois parâmetros.

Exemplo da chamada do procedimento:
`call('1,2,3', '100,200,300')`

Essa é a chamada do procedimento, o procedimento vai receber esses dois campos sendo que cada um desses campos é como se fosse um `array`. Quero saber é como eu consigo fazer um `select` onde eu pesquise por exemplo:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela 
 WHERE codigo = 1
   AND valor = 2
   AND codigo = 2
   AND valor = 20
   AND codigo = 3
   AND valor = 30
```

Porém não conseguir fazer isso, pois tudo é como se fosse um array, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Poste a estrutura da sua tabela.

Comment: Pelo que entendi o primeiro valor se refere ao primeiro serviço, o segundo valor ao segundo serviço até o enésimo.
Então você está procurando um o serviço 1 com o valor 100?
Serviço 2 com valor 200?
select * 
from 
where (codigo = 1 and valor=100) or (codigo = 2 and valor = 200) or (codigo = 3 and valor = 300)
Seria isso?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei se você vai conseguir fazer a consulta, mas tente usando

```
WHERE codigo IN(1, 2, 3) and valor IN(2, 20, 30)
```

Mas o retorno seria qualquer código e valor que você estiver passando.

Acredito que vc terá que usar talvez um UNION, com tantos SELECTs que forem necessários, no seu exemplo seriam 3.